# Using Device mapper thin provisioning on loop devices

Tags: rhel, kvm, loop-device, snapshot, device-mapper

I have several KVM raw files that are read only (about 100gb).

I am adding these raw files as loopback devices.

I then create a snap file to allow the VM to have read/write access to its disk. This allows me to insert modifications, test, wipe the snap and repeat.

Snippet of my perl script:

```perl
$base_file = "/images/vmbase.raw";
$base_stats = stat($base_file);
$base_blocks = $base_stats->size / 512;
$base_size = floor($base_stats->size / 10**6);
system("dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/shm/vmbase.snap count=1 bs=1M seek=$base_size");
$baseloop='losetup -f --show /images/vmbase.raw --read-only';
$snaploop='losetup -f --show /dev/shm/vmbase.snap';
system("dmsetup create vmdrive --table "0  snapshot $baseloop");`
```

This creates a device called `/dev/mapper/vmdrive` that I then attach to my virtual machine. I can use parted `/dev/mapper/vmdrive` to see the available partitions. Now, it would great to switch to thin provisioning to see if I get a performance gain.

Here is what I tried (used the "cookbook" from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/thin-provisioning.txt)

First I create some block devices using loops:

meta: 2GB

snap: 24GB

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/shm/vmbase.meta bs=4096 count=524288
dd if=/dev/zero of=/snaps/vmbase.snap bs=4096 count=5859385
losetup -f /images/vmbase.raw --read-only
losetup -f /dev/shm/vmbase.meta
losetup -f /snaps/vmbase.snap`
```

Then I create the pool device: (assume `loop0` for `raw`, `loop1` for `meta` and `loop2` for `snap`) I use a 1MB block size and 2GB as my low free space threshold

```
$ dmsetup create vmbase-pool \
      --table "0 20971520 thin-pool /dev/loop1 /dev/loop0 2048 2048
```

Follow that up by generating the snap of the external block device (my raw file)

```
$ dmsetup message /dev/mapper/vmbase-pool 0 "create_thin 0"
$ dmsnap create vmsnap \
      --table "0 20971520 thin /dev/mapper/vmbase-pool 0 /dev/loop0"
```

I then attach the `/dev/mapper/vmsnap` device to my virtual machine and it won't boot. When I use parted to print the partition table I get errors. Part of this is I need to be able to launch multiple copies of the virtual machine at once.

I'm using RHEL 6.7 with kernel 2.6.32-573.7.1

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue(s).

1: The data backing volume of a thin-pool needs to be the same size or larger of the base block device. The data backing volume dd creation command should have the same block size and "$base_size" as my original snap.

2: The second number in the table definition of the dmsetup create thin_pool command should be the block device's number of blocks, which is obtained by the following code:

```
my $base_stats = stat($base_file);
my $base_blocks = $base_stats->size / 512;
```

Finally the command to create the thin pool is follows:

```
system("dmsetup create vm-pool\
   --table \"0 $base_blocks thin-pool $meta_lodev $snap_lodev 2048 2048\"");
```